# MOODLE :: Security Single-SignOn

Tags: moodle

Can we restrict an user to login with his/her account using many browsers at a time. That is an user can login using any one browser. (Shouldn't allows users with multiple logIns)

Suppose::we can login with our gmail account from Firefox and at the same time Chrome, IE etc.,

Could anyone suggest with such option in moodle 2.8+

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not totally sure what you mean here.

Provided you mean "how to prevent a user from being logged more than once at any time?", I think the plugin https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=auth_uniquelogin will do it for you.

Be aware it requires "database-stored sessions". It's the default, but if you have a busy site, you might prefer to use memcached instead at some point.